# Post array of images got issues

Tags: objective-c

i am selecting the multiple images from gallery i have to post those images to web service but i got problem to posting only one images i got post any one help me to solve this issues 
Thanks in Advance ....

here is my code

```
-(void)callingUploadBusinessBussinessGalleryImageApi{

    BusinessUser *busUser = [BusinessUser getBusinessUser];
    NSMutableArray *arrImgData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.chosenImages.count; i++) {
     uploadImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self.chosenImages objectAtIndex:i], 0.1);
    [arrImgData insertObject:uploadImageData atIndex:i];

    }

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrImgData];

    //NSData *data =[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:arrImgData format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];
    NSURL *uploadProfPicUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseUrl];
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dataDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:busUser.business_id] forKey:@"business_id"];
    NetworkHandler *networkHandler = [[NetworkHandler alloc] initWithRequestUrl:uploadProfPicUrl withBody:dataDictionary withMethodType:HTTPMethodPOST withHeaderFeild:nil];
    [networkHandler startUploadRequest:@"DirectoryProfilePhoto" withData:data  withType:fileTypeJPGImage withUrlParameter:uploadBusinessGalleryImageUrl withFileLocation:@"imageFile" SuccessBlock:^(id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    } ProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    } FailureBlock:^(NSString *errorDescription, id errorResponse) {

    }];
}
```

here only single image posting to the server i need to send array of image ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send them one by one in background queue if you don't want your application to freeze.

Follow these steps:
1.Call the function to upload first image of the array.

```
[self uploadingMethod];

-(void)uploadingMethod
    {
        //Hit the uploading service here.

        [self uploadtask:0]; //0 being the index of the array

    }

-(void)uploadtask:(int*)IndexNumber
{
  //Upload the image in background thread.
}
```

2.When you get the response of first image being uploaded, again call the uploading function but this time with the incremented index of the array.

```
-(void)uploadingMethod
    {
        //Hit the uploading service here.

        [self uploadtask:1]; //increment this everytime the function is called.

    }
```

Comment: my question is upload array of images

Comment: here i can post only one images but o ahve to post array of images

Comment: Then you'll have to change your uploading code and use AF networking.
And then use it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18204164/6597313

Comment: can u pls post the answer how could i do that

Comment: i need to post array of images in one request '

Comment: Just look up how to send images in multipart data, you'll get your answer.

Comment: i look out that ..i need to send the array of images in one request

Comment: can u please please post the answer

Comment: i am new for the developemnt i dont know how to achive that